# Reducing list of tuples and generating mean values (being pythonic!)

Tags: python, list, tuples, mean

I'm a Python beginner and I have written some code which works (shown at the end) but I'd prefer to learn a pythonic way to do this.

I have a list of lists of tuples, as below. There might be anywhere from 1 to 6 tuples in each list. I'd like to determine the mean of the three numerical values in each of the lists, and end up with just one tuple in each list, so something like the second snippet.

```
[
    [
        ("2022-02-21 20:30:00", None, 331.0),
        ("2022-02-21 21:00:00", None, 324.0),
        ("2022-02-21 21:30:00", None, 298.0),
    ],
    [
        ("2022-02-21 22:00:00", None, 190.0),
        ("2022-02-21 22:30:00", None, 221.0),
        ("2022-02-21 23:00:00", None, 155.0),
    ],
    [
        ("2022-02-21 23:30:00", None, 125.0),
        ("2022-02-22 00:00:00", None, 95.0),
        ("2022-02-22 00:30:00", None, 69.0),
    ],
]
```

```
[
    [
        ("2022-02-21 20:30:00", None, 317.7),
    ],
    [
        ("2022-02-21 22:00:00", None, 188.7),
    ],
    [
        ("2022-02-21 23:30:00", None, 96.3),
    ],
]
```

```
for li in data:
    li = [list(t) for t in li]
    sum = 0

    for t in li:
        sum = sum + t[tuple_idx]

    mean = sum / len(li)

    li[0][tuple_idx] = mean

    new_data.append(tuple(li[0]))

data = new_data
```

Comment: As you said, you could solve this with for loop, show us your code and at what point you aren't being pythonic.

Comment: And is the second value always `None`?

Comment: @gajendragarg I've edited my post to show my existing solution, but it does not feel smart or neat.

Comment: @Jasmijn no, sometimes we are working with [1] and sometimes with [2].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't try to make it more pythonic or shorter but more readable.

So I would keep your version with few small changes.

First I would use names which mean something.

And there is function `sum()` so I wouldn't use it as variable.

```
new_data = []

value_idx = 2

for group in data:
    
    total_sum = sum(item[value_idx] for item in group) 
    mean = total_sum / len(group)
    
    first_item = list(group[0])    
    first_item[value_idx] = mean
    
    new_data.append( [tuple(first_item)] )

data = new_data
```

Comment: Thanks. I see that using the sum() function across all the values in the group is much neater than looping through them and adding it each time explicitly :)

Comment: maybe if you would keep it as normal list 2D then you could use `pandas` and it would be even simpler. BTW: `sum()` replaces `+` so you can use it also for nested lists - ie. `sum([["Hello"], ["World"]], [])` gives flat list `['Hello', 'World']`

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the most pythonic you can get with this:

```
from statistics import fmean

result = [
    [(*x[0][:-1], fmean(map(lambda y: y[2], x)))] for x in inputs
]
```

You can flatten it to a list of tuples if you want by dropping the square brackets inside the comprehension.

Comment: Thank you. That's gonna take some figuring out in my tiny brain :D